# Ambiguity when inner namespace name matches a global namespace name

Tags: c++

Language lawyers, attention!

I've got the following code:

```
namespace conflicting 
{
    struct Foo {};
}

namespace outer
{
    namespace conflicting
    {
        struct Bar {};
    }
}

using namespace outer;

int main()
{
    conflicting::Bar b;
    return 0;
}
```

Using g++ 4.8.2, I get the following errors when attempting to compile:

```
t.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
t.cpp:18:5: error: reference to ‘conflicting’ is ambiguous
     conflicting::Bar b;
     ^
t.cpp:2:1: note: candidates are: namespace conflicting { }
 {
 ^
t.cpp:9:5: note:                 namespace outer::conflicting { }
     {
     ^
t.cpp:18:5: error: reference to ‘conflicting’ is ambiguous
     conflicting::Bar b;
     ^
t.cpp:2:1: note: candidates are: namespace conflicting { }
 {
 ^
t.cpp:9:5: note:                 namespace outer::conflicting { }
     {
     ^
t.cpp:18:22: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘b’
     conflicting::Bar b;
```

Can someone explain to me why this error is happening (maybe reference a section of the standard)?

Comment: Would you expect any other result? Which?

Comment: His point seems to be that since there's only one `Bar` defined, the compiler should be able to know which namespace to look into.

Comment: But to know that it would have to look in both of them, in order to decide which one to look in.

Comment: @VincentSavard, how much do you charge for the crystall ball?

Comment: @VincentSavard How is the compiler supposed to decide which namespace to look in?

Comment: @NathanOliver, why are you asking Vincent? He just clarified OP's question, and i admire his ability.

Comment: Yes, Vincent correctly synthesized my point which I should have made explicit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick summary: For X::m to be a qualified-id, X needs to refer uniquely to a single namespace.

`conflicting::Bar` is a qualified-id if `conflicting` is "a nested-name-specifier that names a namespace" and `Bar` is "the name of a member of that namespace (or the name of a member of a namespace made visible by a using-directive)" (all references are to N3337, and all emphasis is mine):

> 5.1.1 General [expr.prim.general]
>
> 9. A ::, or **a nested-name-specifier that names a namespace** (7.3), in either case followed by t**he name of a member of that namespace (or the name of a member of a namespace made visible by a using-directive)** is a qualified-id; 3.4.3.2 describes name lookup for namespace members that appear in qualified-ids. The result
>      is the member. The type of the result is the type of the member. The result is an lvalue if the member is a function or a variable and a prvalue otherwise.

Section 3.4 describes the process of name lookup, which requires that name lookups find an unambiguous declaration for the name (with overloaded functions being the exception):

> 3.4 Name lookup [basic.lookup]
>
> 1. The name lookup rules apply uniformly to all names (including typedef-names (7.1.3), namespace-names (7.3), and class-names (9.1)) wherever the grammar allows such names in the context discussed by a particular rule. Name lookup associates the use of a name with a declaration (3.1) of that name. **Name lookup shall find an unambiguous declaration for the name (see 10.2).** Name lookup may associate more than one declaration with a name if it finds the name to be a function name; the declarations are said to form a set of overloaded functions (13.1). Overload resolution (13.3) takes place after name lookup has succeeded. The access rules (Clause 11) are considered only once name lookup and function overload resolution (if applicable) have succeeded. Only after name lookup, function overload resolution (if applicable) and access checking have succeeded are the attributes introduced by the name’s declaration used further in expression processing (Clause 5).

The wording of Section 3.4.3.2 makes it clear that the namespace needs to be unique:

> 3.4.3.2 Namespace members [namespace.qual]
>
> 2. For a namespace X and name m, the namespace-qualified lookup set S(X,m) is defined as follows: Let S'(X,m) be the set of all declarations of m in X and the inline namespace set of X (7.3.1). If S'(X,m) is not empty, S(X,m) is S'(X,m); otherwise, S(X,m) is the union of S(N_i,m) for all namespaces Ni nominated by using-directives in X and its inline namespace set.

This description presumes that X is unique, since it doesn't describe any process for iterating through a set of possible namespaces to find m.

Since the compiler can't figure out which `conflicting` namespace to use as the starting point for the namespace member lookup, it gives you an error.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thank you, godel9, that was _exactly_ what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You qualified a name with `conflicting::` so the compiler needs to go and look for `Bar` in that scope ... but which scope? It could refer to two different ones, `::conflicting` or `outer::conflicting` which can be referred to without the `outer::` prefix because of the using-directive.

Answer (score -1):

Yo do not need a language lawer for this! Once you introduced `outer` namespace into your current namespace (by `using` it) all it's names became visible. So now you have a conflict.

This is why I strongly discurage the practice of `using` a namespace. Namespaces were invented for a reason, and the reason is to prevent such issues.